# how to do a RoleGuard with angular 6?

Tags: angular

How can I bring the user role from the token?

I bring the token using `angular2-jwt` decode but when I want to put a

CanAccess admin route it sends me a `false` value

when I do a `console.log(tokenPayLoad)` it brings me the decoded token

[image]

and in the **Apshowsation** view of Chrome DevTools, it shows the user in localStorage

[image]

this is my route declaration

```
  { 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, 
    canActivate: [RoleGuard], 
    data: {expectedRole: 'admin'} 
  },
```

this is my `role-guard.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { AuthService } from '../user/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService()

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const tokenPayLoad = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token)

    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated() || tokenPayLoad.role !== expectedRole) {
      console.log(tokenPayLoad)
      this.router.navigate(['/'])
      window.alert('No tienes permisos para acceder a esta ruta.')
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the `console.log` of the decoded token, it doesn't appear to contain a role

Comment: @user184994 thanks :D, I forgot to change the 'jwt.sign'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the help of user184994 I see that I forgot to save the role into the token

so I put the role into the token

```
const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id, role: user.role }...
```